# Is there a good JS ranged datepicker control out there?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a JS control that provides a similar experience to the datepicker on Google Analytics

[image: GA screenshot]

Comment: still interested in this question...any news here? the provided answers look outdated...obviously, almost 4 years later.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the jQueryUI datepicker, it's very effective and easy to set up.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

There is also an extension for the date picker from JqueryUI and a tutorial here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/alaaalnajjar/archive/2010/05/04/how-to-use-jquery-date-range-picker-plugin-in-asp-net.aspx